# ubuntu deletes (raid) mbr?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 2 disk win 10 raid array which i keep for games. I also have a SSD which i have loaded Ubuntu 20.10.

However I found that my windows selection was gone and in the bios my raid array had "failed". I reloaded windows 10 and tried the same thing and alas it failed my raid and lost the MBR. No amount of fixmbr would help.

Ubuntu is not the only distro that does this - but strangely I have been loading Ubuntu/other distros for a long time with no MBR repercussions. Fast boot is off in bios.

Is there anything else in bios I may have tinkered with that would effect win 10 MBR?

Comment: Make sure that when you are installing Ubuntu that when it asks where the bootloader should go that you are choosing the SSD drive that you are installing Ubuntu to.  During the installation the installer usually defaults to the first drive or `/dev/sda` for the bootloader, but it should allow you to choose where the bootloader goes.

Comment: On my own installs (non-QA installs) I always use *something else* so I specify where I want things to go.  I have noted some (non-Something-else) installs want to write to different drives to where I intended, but the summary of what will occur (if you okay it) always makes it known, so you can back out & correct.  FYI:  `fixmbr` just re-writes the first 512 bytes of the disk, which is mostly a pointer (if where it pointed to no longer exists, it'll be pointing nowhere so won't work; it doesn't impact partitioning, just a pointer in first 512 bytes of disk)

Answer (score 1):

BIOS boot or UEFI boot?

With BIOS, you can select which drive to install grub boot loader.

But with UEFI, Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs to first drive. Multiple work arounds. Please add to old bug report. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.

Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. (I have not had that work, but others have.)

Or if you have ESP on second or external drive, you can just reinstall grub, either manually or using Boot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall to correct drive.